# Pixel rounding and overflow:scroll

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, pixel

I understand that floating point numbers are not easily represented in binary, thus percentage-based widths are not always accurately displayed, but I'd like some clarification on a specific, very simple example here. Consider the following ([fiddle for ease of testing](https://jsfiddle.net/41tj3kzb/1/)):

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
div {
  width:40%;
  height:300px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

When the browser is resized, the background color flashes in and out to the right of the scrollbar as the element resizes. I'm confused as to why that is, as I assume that the scrollbar would move at the same rate as the container, always sticking to the right side of it. Instead, it seems the scrollbar is moving it at a different rate than the element.

Furthermore, and even more strange in my opinion, when the mouse is released at a window width wherein the background **is not** showing to the right of the element, the behavior persists on the next resize. But when the mouse is released at a window width wherein the background **is** showing to the right of the element, the scrollbar jumps to the right to cover the background and justify itself to the right edge where it belongs, and then the behavior seems to be fixed for all future resizing until the browser is refreshed. This is very strange to me.

Additionally, the behavior is not present on every refresh. It seems to be random, about 1 out of every 2-3 refreshes.

***WHAAAAAAAAAAAAT***

So then, **why** does the background color show to the right of the scrollbar during resize? And **why** does releasing the mouse when the background is showing temporarily fix the issue barring a page refresh?

Please do not mark this as a duplicate of a question about floating point numbers in binary. I'm interested in an explanation of *this specific issue*. Thank you.

Comment: the other question where you answered is already dealing with this, why repeating?

Comment: @TemaniAfif because i just spent 2 hours trying to figure this out and the other question is long gone from the queue. I figured if i made a simplified example and expanded the specifics of the behavior i could get some good answers from knowledgeable devs. Is that not a good thing to do?

Comment: *the other question is long gone from the queue* --> this is not a valid reason to repeat the same question. It was asked only 3h hours ago and already have 2 upvotes so it's not yet *lost* in the queue and can receive answers at any time. Even if it doesn't get an answer, you can consider adding a bounty in 48h.

Comment: is that happening in every browsers ? , how long has your browser been opened ? how many page do you have opened ? Which OS ? how much memory left you have .... your fiddle doesn't show any flickering to me, nor i noticed such  behavior so far. could you clarify a few things ? for the pixel rounding it can vary from a pixel on resize indeed

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree with you, but I do not think this is the same question. While it is the same behavior, this is a much more detailed question. Do you really think I should close this question? I'd really like an answer here.'

Comment: @G-Cyr the duplicate question shows this behavior more clearly since it's a more complex code. I cannot see it here too

Comment: @Claire it's the same question because you are describing the same behavior and you what to understand why. You simply wrote the question differently but the main issue is the same and the answers will be the same.

Comment: @TemaniAfif the duplicate question shows the same behavior. It is only present every second or third refresh in either instance.

Comment: on my side, I don't see this behavior on your code here. Tried all the resizing, zooming and refreshing while I can see it in the duplicate one

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see the behavior perfectly inside the fiddle. This is why I'm confused by your duplicate mark. I get your point, but I do think this is a much better way to present the problem. So again, are you saying I should close this?

Comment: @G-Cyr I'm in Firefix 68.0.1

Comment: @claire idem, same browser

Comment: @G-Cyr you don't see it inside the fiddle?

Comment: the question is already *closed* you probably mean *delete*. You are not obliged to deleted it because this question will rederict anyone who will visit it to the original one so it can be helpful. In all the cases we need to have the answers inside the same question dealing with the same issue even if the explanation isn't the same. As a side note, you can edit the other question to add more details without changing the author intent of course.

Comment: @Claire nop, i do not .

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok fine thank you. If you have any insight or you can expand on my answer to the other question please do so.

Comment: @G-Cyr try playing with the percentage width values in either example. like I said here, sometimes it shows the behavior and sometimes it does not.